# Typescript get property only available in one of union

Tags: javascript, typescript

To start with: I'm a total Typescript noob so please bear with me.

I've made a small use-case(At the bottom of this post) in which I have an array which can contain both "Class One" and "Class Two". I want to loop through that array with a `forEach` and act when the property `drawer` is present.

The problem that Typescript gives me in my forEach loop(Where I try to log `drawer`) is:

```
Property 'drawer' does not exist on type 'One | Two'.
  Property 'drawer' does not exist on type 'Two'.
```

Whilst it is clearly present in `One`.

When I set my `arrayWithBothOneAndTwo` to `let arrayWithBothOneAndTwo = [] as One[]` it won't give me the problem of drawer not existing in my forEach loop but since it does contain Two I don't think thats a proper solution and will throw other errors.

Changing my forEach loop to

```
    arrayWithBothOneAndTwo.forEach((item: One) => {
      console.log(item.drawer)
    })
```

Gives me the error:

```
Argument of type '(item: One) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: One | Two, index: number, array: (One | Two)[]) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'item' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'One | Two' is not assignable to type 'One'.
      Property 'drawer' is missing in type 'Two' but required in type 'One'.
```

***So in Short:***

How can I use `item.drawer` in my forEach without throwing errors in my code?

```
    class One {
      drawer: string[] = []

      constructor () {
        this.drawer.push('A')
        this.drawer.push('B')
        this.drawer.push('C')
      }
    }

    class Two {
      notADrawer: string[] = []

      constructor () {
        this.notADrawer.push('D')
        this.notADrawer.push('E')
        this.notADrawer.push('F')
      }
    }

    // make an array with some one classes
    const someOnes = [new One(), new One()]
    // make an array with some two classes
    const someTwos = [new Two(), new Two(), new Two(), new Two()]

    // init an array which can contain both One or Two 
    let arrayWithBothOneAndTwo = [] as Array<One | Two>

    // populate array with some One classes and some Two classes
    arrayWithBothOneAndTwo = [...someOnes, ...someTwos]
    
    // Loop through it and show the drawer array (if present)
    arrayWithBothOneAndTwo.forEach((item) => {
      console.log(item.drawer)
    })
```

Comment: Protip: just avoid using `Array.forEach` and use the modern `for(of)` loop instead.

Comment: Also, using `as` in TypeScript is usually a sign you're doing something wrong, even (or rather: _especially_!) if using `as` brushes `tsc` errors under the rug. I'd love to see a TypeScript compiler flag that disallows unsafe use of `as`, tbh.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup; since I'm a total noob: Could you come up with a solution for the `as` in this case?

Comment: You can do just `const arrayWithBothOneAndTwo = [...someOnes, ...someTwos];`

Comment: For an empty array, you can define the type as follows: `const arrayWithBothOneAndTwo: (One | Two)[] = [];`

Comment: Thanks Robby but that gives me `Array type using 'T[]' is forbidden for non-simple types. Use 'Array<T>' instead`

Comment: Not getting that on my local setup and on the playground. Maybe you have an eslint/tslint rule that introduces that restriction? Anyhow, it would have to be `const arrayWithBothOneAndTwo: Array<One | Two> = [];` for your case then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get TypeScript to correctly [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) the type, you have to add a check to see whether the property is present:

```
arrayWithBothOneAndTwo.forEach((item) => {
    if('drawer' in item) {
        console.log(item.drawer); // type of item now narrowed to One
    }
});
```

If you want, you can make that more explicit with a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) in a user-defined type guard:

```
arrayWithBothOneAndTwo.forEach((item) => {
    if(isOne(item)) {
        console.log(item.drawer);
    }
});

function isOne(item: One | Two): item is One {
  return 'drawer' in item;
}
```

Comment: That's the one. Nice! It's good to know that you have to narrow it down to prevent this. I didn't notice it was more of a warning persé but this makes it alot easier to comprehend.